# Single login page for different types of users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an application that allows users to register either as a **category 1** or **category 2** or both. Simply put, a user can register under category 1, and also register under category 2, using the same details.

With this is mind, I've thought of some ways to store the users details in my database:

1. Use a single table, where I'll differentiate the categories using roles or permissions.
2. Use two tables, where I'll store users based on their choice (upon registration), in their respective tables.

After considering things like:

- Users can choose to register in both categories,
- Users can decide to use the same details for both categories;

I drew up a conclusion that my option one will not give me what I want.

And now, to my code, I have created my `User` class, which I use for the registration and also logging in of users.

```
class User {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName,
            $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if( Session::exists($this->_sessionName) ) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if( $this->find($user) ){

                    $this->_isLogggedIn = true;

                } else {

                    $this->logout();

                }
            }
        } else {

            $this->find($user);

        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'email';

            if ( $packageType == 'category1' ) {
                $fCheck = $this->_db->get('table_name', array($field, '=', $user));

                if( $fCheck->count() ) {
                    $this->_data = $fCheck->first();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            elseif ( $packageType == 'category2' ) {
                $iCheck = $this->_db->get('table_name', array($field, '=', $user));

                if($iCheck->count()) {
                    $this->_data = $iCheck->first();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($userInput = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($userInput);

        if($user) {
            if(password_verify($password, $this->data()->password)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    public function logout() {
        Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    }

    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_isLogggedIn;
    }
}
```

The code works without having to define or check for `$packageType` in my `find()` method, when using a single table, but as I pointed out, I need to use it for different tables.

What I'm stuck with right now is how I can check for the specific package which a user is logging in to, using the `User` class, and get the corresponding user detail(s), for that particular table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Make a solution that uses both options you have available to achieve a better organization of information on your system.

Using the way your database is right now (two tables only), you have to find the user on both tables. That means you search first on one of them and, if you don't find the user, search on the other one. This means you'll have to figure out a priority system, where of the tables will have priority over the other.

However, as you said before:

> I drew up a conclusion that my option one will not give me what I want.

It actually won't completely solve your problem, as you need your users to log in under a single username and have access to both categories.

So, since the first option only solves half of your problem, let's check the other one.
Option 2 uses one table for users. This is great, because this means every user will have a single username. However, your requirements need two tables (maybe category1 has something category2 doesn't or vice-versa?), so this doesn't fit.

Since option 1 is half of the solution and option 2 is the other half, let's use both!

Your database will now have three tables: a table for category1, a table for category2 and a table for users. Your category tables will have user info specific for your categories, and your user table will have username and password info for each user.
Your category tables won't have a primary key, only a foreign key (referencing the PK of the user table). On login, your system will have to ask in which category the user wants to log into. After he selects a category, you can search for user info on either category1 or category2 depending on which one the user chose.

And that's it! You now have a login system supporting multiple users with multiple permission levels and user info.